# cromwell files downloaded from a URL have too strict permissions

Tags: wdl

Cromwell can download files that are URLs (i.e. URLs in the inputs.json).  However, the permissions of these files, once they are downloaded, are very strict (`rw------- bmac bmac`).  I was wondering if there was a way to control the file permissions of said files; I need them accessible to other users.

Cromwell uses a library called `akka.http` to download url-files.  As stated in the
[cromwell configuration docs](https://cromwell.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Configuring/):

> Cromwell uses akka-http to serve requests. For more advanced
> configuration settings, refer to the akka-http documentation.

If I run cromwell with the given files
`java -jar ~/cromwell/cromwell-84.jar run fq_count.wdl -i fq_count.url.json`

I see the permissions for the url-input file:

```
ls -l cromwell-executions/fq_count/2a65649a-999e-44ef-bec8-89953e0e3f1f/call-count_reads/inputs/429920399/12673489687364390176
-rw-------  2 bmac  bmac
```

Question:  Is there a way to control the file permissions, i.e. through akka.http or other?

**WDL**

```
version 1.0
workflow fq_count {
    input {
        File fastq_file
    }
    call count_reads {
      input: fastq = fastq_file
    }
}

task count_reads {
  input {
    File fastq
    String memory = "5G"
    String time = "00:10:00"
  }

  command <<<
    set -euo pipefail
    fastq='~{fastq}'
    extension="${fastq##*.}"

    if [ "${extension}" = 'gz' ]; then
  cat_cmd='zcat'
else
  cat_cmd='cat'
fi
# using awk instead of bc as bc isn't in debian slim images
"${cat_cmd}" "~{fastq}" | wc -l | awk '{ print int($1/4) }' > num_reads.txt
  >>>

  output {
    File num_reads = "num_reads.txt"
  }

  runtime {
    cpu: 1
    memory: memory
    time: time
  }
}
```

**Input json**

```
{       
  "fq_count.fastq_file": https://portal.nersc.gov/cfs/m342/jaws/test_data/sample.fastq"
}
```

Comment: Is adding a `chmod` command to the end an option? Ugly, but it might work.